# Wicked_pdf generate my PDF with strange characters, but when I use the Controller render everything is quite good

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I'm new with wicked_pdf gem, but i notice something weird with the generation of PDF, I use the gem with two purpose, one, to show a quotation and the second one to send the PDF via email.

In my show action in Controller I have something like this:

```
def show
    @lot_quotation =  set_lot_quotation
    authorize @lot_quotation
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        filename = 'cotizacion_' + @lot_quotation.id.to_s
        render pdf: "lot_quotation", 
              layout: 'lot_quotation.html.erb',
              page_size: 'Letter',
              save_to_file: Rails.root.join('pdfs', "#{filename}.pdf")
      end
    end
  end
```

Everything is great!

Then I have an action "send_quotation", that generates the PDF and then I use ActionMailer to send it... here is my code:

```
def send_quotation
    @lot_quotation = LotQuotation.find(params[:id])
    filename = 'cotizacion_' + @lot_quotation.id.to_s + '.pdf'
    html = render_to_string template: 'lot_quotations/show.pdf.erb', layout: "lot_quotation.html", pdf: "lot_quotation", 
      page_size: "Letter", encoding: 'UTF-8' 
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html) 
    # then save to a file
    save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs',filename)
    File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
      file << pdf
    end
    SeruMailer.cotizacion(params[:email_to], @lot_quotation)

    authorize @lot_quotation
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

It, works, but... when I open the pdf file, I have stuff like this:

```
%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (þÿCotizacion) /Creator (þÿwkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1) /Producer (þÿQt 4.8.6) /CreationDate (D:20150508165111-04'00') >> endobj 3 0 obj <<
/Type /ExtGState /SA true /SM 0.02 /ca 1.0 /CA 1.0 /AIS false /SMask /None>> endobj 4 0 obj [/Pattern /DeviceRGB] endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image
/Width 351 /Height 69 /BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /Length 7 0 R /Filter /DCTDecode >> stream ÿØÿà​JFIF​​​``ÿÛC​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​ ​​ ​​​ ​​​​​​​​
​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ÿÛC​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ÿÀ​ ​ E​ _​ ​ "​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ÿÄ​ ​ ​ ​ ​
​ ÿÄμ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ }​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ !1A​ ​ Qa​ "q​ 2​ ‘¡​ #B±Á​ RÑð$3br‚​ ​ ​ ​ ​ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„... †‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–— ̃TMš¢£¤¥¦§ ̈©a23 ́μ¶· ̧1oÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​
​ ÿÄμ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ w​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ !1​ ​ AQ​ aq​ "2​ ​ ​ B‘¡±Á#3Rð​ brÑ​ $4á%ñ​ ​ ​ ​ &'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„... †‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–— ̃TMš¢£¤¥¦§ ̈©a23 ́μ¶· ̧1oÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ?ýü¢Šà~'þÒžøC​ þÜÖí#Ÿμ
 ́N$​ ÿà​ ​ ßUMWW¶Ðt÷o1⁄4 ̧‚Ö​ ÇÏ$®​ ​ ñ5ñ ̄Å¿ø*​ ÕÜ/oàí​ -​
éúüïtÿr>õóWÄ​ Œþ*ø§xòëoÖ¡ ̈​ Ñ​ ÿwÿ|P​ Ý_​ ÿà¡Þ​ øy​ Ä​ t×​ %Ô​ |‘Y​ ​ ​ ûmÒ1⁄4oÃßðTÝuÿ† ̈ðN1ÿãIÿ¿0​ ñ​ ÙþÍ3⁄4​ OˆŸ2Ýî​ ,2[%ý
```

I have no idea why? Am I missing something? I already checked the github issues, questions and stuff like that... but i found no clue... I think is something related to render_to_string.

EDIT

Here is my layout app/views/layouts/lot_quotation.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

       <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <style>
      body {font-size: 11px !important;}
      h3 {font-size: 12px !important;}
      table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
      }
      h2 {font-size: 14px !important;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <title>Cotizacion</title>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is lot_quotation.html.erb really your layout: or should that be template: ?

Comment: Hello Antarr, yes it is my layout, i double checked it!, please check my post i already edited it, Thanks, do you have any idea?

Comment: Post your template for pdf. i.e(send_quotation.pdf.erb)

Comment: Are you just looking at the PDF with a text editor? Because you can't just read the PDF text in a text editor, it's compressed, and you wouldn't see HTML inside of it, because it is using an entirely different markup format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will be more than enough if you just want to render the pdf:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: 'file_name',
             template: 'orders/order_success_new_design.pdf.erb',
             layout: 'layouts/application_new.pdf.erb'
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to save as pdf:

```
def save
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
                        render_to_string(
                          template: 'example/pdf_view.pdf.erb',
                          layout: 'layouts/application.pdf.erb'))
  send_data(pdf,
            filename: 'file_name.pdf',
            type: 'application/pdf',
            disposition: 'attachment') 
end
```

Comment: There might be some case with the **encoding**. Refer [**WickedPDF**](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) for more options.

Comment: Just with template and layout were enough to generate the PDF, i think it was a problem with the encoding, Thank you very much!